# shiny conditionalPanel() JS condition not working with bslib

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, bslib

Using `shiny` 1.6.0 and `bslib` 0.3.0.

This work as expected:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(
    title = "Minimal Example Issue",
    id = "tabs",
    header = conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.tabs == 'tab_1'",
            HTML("Special tab 1")
        ),
    tabPanel("tab_1", "Hello"),
    tabPanel("tab_2", "Hi")
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This doesn't as the condition isn't met on selection of `tab_1`:

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_navbar(
    title = "Minimal Example Issue",
    id = "tabs",
    header = conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.tabs == 'tab_1'",
            HTML("Special tab 1")
        ),
    nav("tab_1", "Hello"),
    nav("tab_2", "Hi")
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I would like to understand which JS element has replaced the `input.tabs` in the second example.

Answer (score 0):

upgrading shiny to 1.7.0 (now on CRAN) fix it